# Random SQLite database update null exception

Tags: android

First, let me say, that this exception doesn't happen regularly, it happened to me only few times, unfortunately never when phone was connected and being debugged. 
All information I got about is from Developer Console logs and app logs that users have sent me.

First, all information I got was from Developer Console:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

when calling:

```
//private SQLiteDatabase mDb; initialized earlier
ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
args.put(KEY_ENABLED, isEnabled);

return mDb.update(DATABASE_TABLE, args, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0; //exception here
```

Guessing that it may be caused by mDb being null somehow, I have added logging here, to know what exactly is happening

```
//DbAdapter 
public boolean updateIsAlarmChecked(long rowId, boolean isEnabled) {
try {
    ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
    args.put(KEY_ENABLED, isEnabled);

    return mDb.update(DATABASE_TABLE, args, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
} catch (Exception e) {
    Utils.log("updateIsAlarmChecked exception: " + e.getMessage());
    Utils.log("alarm enabled: " + isEnabled);
    Utils.log("db is " + (mDb == null ? "null" : "not null"));
    return false;
}
}
```

Unfortunately, received logs contain:

```
updateIsAlarmChecked exception: null
alarm enabled: true
db is not null
```

So it looks like it is something inside SQLiteDatabase, but how can I find out what exactly? Or maybe it is not, as Developer Console didn't show no trace from within that class?

I will also write what actions cause that error, maybe that will help

1. Application working normally (as far as I know), Activity A visible
2. User edits an alarm - new Activity B is opened, where informations about alarm are read from newly created and opened DbAdapter (class similar to one from NotePad Android example, I may provide more code if needed).
3. User finishes edits, they are saved correctly, B is finishing returning result with intent. Its DbAdapter is closed in onDestroy (I just noticed that and I know it is incorrect, as onDestroy is not always called. Could that be cause of the error? However I just tried running with commented out closing and there error didn't occur)
4. onActivityResult is called in A, calling A's DbAdapter instance's updateIsAlarmChecked (maybe this instance is getting "incorrect" sometimes?)
5. exception occurs and is catched, update is unsuccessful

Any ideas? All help greatly appreciated

---

Edit:
Small update after newest logs. 
Now code looks like that:

```
ContentValues args = null;
try {
    args = new ContentValues();
    args.put(KEY_ENABLED, isEnabled);
     return mDb.update(DATABASE_TABLE, args, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0; //null exception here
} catch (Exception e) {
    Utils.log("alarm enabled: " + isEnabled); //true
    Utils.log("alarm id= " + rowId); //there is alarm with this rowId
    Utils.log("db is " + (mDb == null ? "null" : "not null")); //not null
    Utils.log("args is " + (args == null ? "null" : "not null")); //not null
    Logger.logException(e);
    return false;
}
```

Worst thing is, stack trace points only to line with return statements - shouldn't it lead further "into" update method?
Any ideas at all what I can do with that? It is terrible, that it happens only sometimes and only thing I can reply to user is "try doing it again, it fails only sometimes"...

Answer (score 0):

I think that you get that problem because of the way you save your `database`! In this link: [Sqlite](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html), `SQLite` does not have a separate `Boolean` storage class. Instead, `Boolean` values are stored as `integers` 0 (`false`) and 1 (`true`). So, I think that you should try to save your `bool` value as 0 or 1.

Comment: Wouldn't that mean error would happen every time on given device? As I wrote it happened to me 2-3 times of hundreds edits that I performed. Also, I am using boolean this way in many other situations and that never caused any problems, so I don't think that is the case

Comment: @Koger: You should show us more error! Because I never store Boolean value in database before, so I not sure it is ok or not! If there no error with save database with `Boolean` values, there no problem with those code above, too! So, show us more error log!!

Comment: What more error can I show you, this is the only one that I am getting. I am storing boolean values in SQLite since start and that never caused any trouble, so I am pretty sure that has nothing to do with it. But if you are sure that storing booleans causes troubles, then that may depend on Android version or something like that, let me know if you know about anything like that